# Extract text before third - "Dash" in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Can you please help to get this code for SQL?

I have column name INFO_01 which contain info like:
D10-52247-479-245 HALL SO

and I would like to extract only
D10-52247-479

I want the part of the text before the third "-" dash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a combination of SUBSTR and INSTR will return what you want:

```
SELECT SUBSTR('D10-52247-479-245', 0, INSTR('D10-52247-479-245', '-', -1, 1)-1) AS output
  FROM DUAL
```

### Result:

```
output
-------------
D10-52247-479
```

### Use:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(t.column, 0, INSTR(t.column, '-', -1, 1)-1) AS output
  FROM YOUR_TABLE t
```

### Reference:

- [SUBSTR](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/substr.php)
- [INSTR](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/instr.php)

### Addendum

If using Oracle10g+, you can use regex via [REGEXP_SUBSTR](http://psoug.org/reference/regexp.html).

Comment: I am sure you can take it from here , but this is not the same as "text before the third dash" everytime. If that is your requirement, you are better off using instr(....,'-',1,3) to be precise and accurate.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to get the position of the third dash (using instr) and then use substr to get the necessary part of the string.

```
with temp as (
    select 'D10-52247-479-245 HALL SO' test_string from dual)
select test_string,
       instr(test_string,1,3) third_dash,
       substr(test_string,1,instr(test_string,1,3)-1) result
  from temp
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple statement that should work:

`SELECT SUBSTR(column, 1, INSTR(column,'-',1,3) ) FROM table;`

Comment: Hi it returned D10-52247-479- and I want only D10-52247-479 without Dash...almost done please help if possible to complete the code.

Comment: SELECT SUBSTR(column, 1, INSTR(column,'-',1,3)-1 ) FROM table;

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming MySQL, let me know if I'm wrong here. But using [SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) you could do the following:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, '-', 3)
```

**EDIT**
Appears to be oracle. Looks like we may have to resort to [REGEXP_SUBSTR](http://psoug.org/reference/regexp.html#ress)

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(column, '^((?.*\-){2}[^\-]*)')
```

*Can't test, so not sure what kind of result that will have...*

Comment: Oracle's REGEXP functionality is supported Oracle10g+

Comment: I will fully admit I am out of my element with oracle. If it works, it's a miracle (or at least a point in a decent direction). Oracle gurus feel free to chime in.

Comment: D10-52247-479- is what it returns

Comment: If it does work, SO should implement a kudos button just for that post (or a PreparationH button, whichever is fine by me) **EDIT** Change it to this (forgot I grouped last hyphen as well): `^((?.*\-){2}[^\-]*)`